# WPF - Best code architecture for handling numerous tab items in Mainwindow

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a WPF application where the homepage (aka MainWindow) will contain several tabs.

I'm wondering what would be the best approach/architecture to encapsulate code specific to each tab instead of coding everything in the same place ?

*NOTE*

After some research I found [`UserControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) class, but I've always thought that class was use in order to avoid re-coding the same logic over and over. In my case I would be using them once for every tab.

Comment: Use MVVM. Have a main viewmodel, which has a child viewmodel property for each tab (and maybe other child viewmodels as well). Use datatemplates to associate the child viewmodel types with views. Implement views as UserControls.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I see. Interesting approach.

Comment: re: your last question, you talked me into it. There's a place here for that answer (though it might be here already). There are people for whom it's legitimately not obvious. Not sure what's to be done though.

Comment: @EdPlunkett what do you mean exactly ?

Comment: I mean that question shouldn't have been downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: @EdPlunkett this is what Stack have become honestly. I'm done posting question on this site. Closing flag are so opinion based it's ironic. see that [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely) I could easily argue that refering to git doc would be an really easy way to accomplish the question yet it gives a ton of reputation to someone that answered an obvious question.

Comment: Nothing to the quality of that answer btw just underlying a big problem with Stack in my opnion at the moment. All comes down on perception of the first few viewers with rep on your question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your preference and desired level of complexity, you can use [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034333/476284) or just create a [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.usercontrol) for every tab to better distribute the code. Resulting in your window's xaml looking something like:

```
<TabItem x:Name="tab_peerView" Header="Peers (Lobby)" Visibility="Visible">
    <Views:SomeUserControl1 />
</TabItem>
<TabItem x:Name="tab_PrepCheckList" Header="Prep" Visibility="Visible">
    <Views:SomeUserControl2 x:Name="view_prep" />
</TabItem>
```

Doing this method you can also offload things like command bindings and respective Execute and CanExecute to the UserControls.